# Deeplink from facebook always open in browser not from the app

Tags: android, deep-linking, android-deep-link

**Deeplink** is not working when link post on **facebook** or **messenger**.It's always redirecting to mobile browser,but when  deeplink shared on skype or other platform its working fine for me.
From facebook when app redirecting to browser i found a 3 dot button on top right and i also found open in [My app] option.When i click it its pefectly redirecting to my app.

> **Expectations**: I want to click my **deeplink** url from **facebook** or **messenger** and it will automatically open my app to a specific page that i want to navigate.

Comment: Do you use Applink? https://developer.android.com/training/app-links?hl=tr

Comment: yeah i am using applink.I have verified the domain as well as from skype or other platform its perfectly working but when it came from facebook the link is opening from browser. Any solution regarding this issue?